# Avoiding hitting SQL Server db multiple times via the `mssql` package in Node

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I am using the `mssql` package in my Node app to query our SQL Server database. One thing I need to do is look up records from a table that match the IDs I have stored from a separate query to a different SQL database.

Because our SQL Server database is large and always growing, rather than get ALL the records, currently I am doing this to pull in only the records that match on an ID from my array:

```
const sourceArr = [
  {id: 1, name: "Joe", notes_detail_id: 123}, 
  {id: 2, name: "Jane", notes_detail_id: 456}, 
  {id: 1, name: "Billy", notes_detail_id: 789}
];

const getMatchingRecords = async function() {
  const targetRecords = [];
  const query = `SELECT NoteDetailsId
  FROM SL_Empsheets
  WHERE NoteDetailsId = ${record.notes_detail_id}`;
    for (let record of sourceArr) {
      let matchingRecord = await sqlServerQueryHandler(query);
      if (matchingRecord) {
        targetRecords.push(matchingRecord);
      }
    }
    return targetRecords;
};
```

And FYI, my `sqlServerQueryHandler()` looks like this:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('./../../../configuration/sql-server-config');

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();

pool.on('error', err => {
  console.log(err);
});

module.exports = async function sqlServerQueryHandler(query) {
  try {
    await poolConnect;
    const request = pool.request();
    const result = await request.query(query);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

My current implementation will work. However, this ends up hitting the database multiple times.

So, my question is, is there a way I do something similar via the `mssql` package, but where I can pass in an array of values, rather than having to iterate through the array and hit the database one record at a time?

Comment: What about a builded query ? Something like "SELECT NoteDetailsId
    FROM RP_Empsheets
    WHERE NoteDetailsId = firstId OR NoteDetailsId = secondId OR NoteDetailsId = thirdId (etcetera)" ?

Comment: I won't know exactly how many original records there will be to match to, as that will change over time, so I wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Of course i mean that "firstId", "secondId" ectetera are provided by your array.

Comment: What would that look like? Do you mean do that within the loop?

Comment: "I wouldn't be able to do this"...why not? Build up the SQL string gradually, by looping through your array and adding another section of the WHERE clause to the SQL each time. Probably neater to write it as an `IN` rather than a series of `OR`s

Comment: I'm open to that. Just trying to picture what that would look like. Could you show me a basic example?

Comment: show us how you use/call the getMatchingRecords function currently, then it'll be a bit easier to suggest something. I'm assuming you already use some sort of loop to work through each of the records from the original table. So you'd just use that to gradually create a single SQL query (rather than trigger a series of queries), and then you'd execute that query after the loop ends.

Comment: I added more code above. The array is being stored in my Node project, and looks like it does above - an array of objects, with properties on the object. I am looping through and matching on the value of one of those properties on each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance it looks like your `getMatchingRecords` function may not be copied correctly, otherwise, i'm not sure where your initial variable `record` is coming from. I think you should be building the query inside the for loop rather than before it.

Assuming that is the case, you could use an `IN` statement in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

You could write this in JS like so:

```
const getMatchingRecords = async function() {
    const queryIn = sourceArr.map(r => r.notes_detail_id);
    const query = `SELECT NoteDetailsId
                   FROM SL_Empsheets
                   WHERE NoteDetailsId IN (${queryIn})`;
    return sqlServerQueryHandler(query);
};
```

Comment: I added some additional code above, to show you what the array looks like.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, you don't need the `join()` on the first part. Just do `const queryIn = sourceArr.map(r => r.notes_detail_id);`